# What's the best idiomatic way of putting a line in a diary about visiting some family whose last name you don't know?

Tags: phrase-request

What's the best idiomatic way of putting a line in a diary about visiting some family whose last name you don't know?

For example, today I have visited Jack and Marry, but I don't know their last name. What should I write?

Could it be like:

> 1. Paid a visit to Jack and Marry's home.

or

> 2. Paid a visit of Jack and Marry's home.

or

> 3. Paid a visit to Jack and Marry's house.

or

> 4. Paid a visit of Jack and Marry's house.

or

> 5. Paid a visit of Jack and Marry's.

or

> 6. Paid a visit to Jack and Marry's.

or is there a better way yet?

NOTE: By "the best idiomatic way" I mean the way a native English speaker (preferably an American) would put that.

EDIT: I understand that a verb "visit/visited" might be very suitable here; however, I am very much interested in whether using the noun "visit" may also be idiomatic in this situation.

Comment: Please do some minimal research  before posting questions which are answerable with a dictionary. See Merriam-Webster: [*He paid a visit **to** his parents.*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pay%20a%20visit%20to#:~:text=%3A%20to%20go%20somewhere%20to%20spend,a%20visit%20to%20his%20parents.) That would already eliminate three of the six options.

Comment: Using the verb *visited* is the most idiomatic way, "to pay a visit to" is quite formal, suitable in a report, essay or a very formal letter, but unlikely in a native speaker's personal diary.

Comment: Saying that, the answer to this question contradicts my experience [“Visit” vs “pay a visit to”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/128354/visit-vs-pay-a-visit-to) I would say "I visited some friends" rather than "I paid a visit to some friends".

Comment: I'd say your number 6 sounds most natural and idiomatic to me. "Paid a visit to Jack and Mary's." (Or "Paid a visit to Jack and Mary.")

Comment: @Mari-LouA - "*Please do some minimal research before posting questions which are answerable with a dictionary. See Merriam-Webster. That would already eliminate three of the six options*" - But Webster doesn't say that "of" or other prepositions are never to be used in this case. Besides, in my experience, many times what Webster says is too official as opposed to the idiomatic and common. For example, you won't find "What can I do you for?" in Webster. Thanks for all your input here.

Comment: "*But Webster doesn't say that "of" or other prepositions are never to be used in this case.*" No, it doesn't because "never" is an absolute expression and there are always exceptions to every rule. And if they had to list all the prepositions which are excluded and explain why, the dictionary would most probably  triple in size. You asked for the `best idiomatic` (normally we'd say "most" in this instance) not whether one or more forms  could *never* be used.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - And that was exactly my point. Webster doesn't always give you the most idiomatic way. See my example with "What can I do you for?

Comment: *See my example with "What can I do you for?* I would argue that is a humorous American English expression that  has little to with it being *more idiomatic* than  "What can I do for you?" or "What would you like to buy?" The latter two examples are the most commonly used among all native speakers.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I see. It looks like I misunderstood the meaning of the word "idiomatic" in English. In my first language the word "idiomatic" means an expression that has some "hidden" meaning in it that cannot be inferred merely from the words contained in it. In other words, the whole phrase is like a separate word. And quite often the meaning implied by it is funny or humorous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Visit Jack and Mary.*

*Visited Jack and Mary.*

---

Using a noun

*Paid Jack and Mary a visit.*

---

**Note**

It's not impossible that someone be called *Marry* but a more likely name is *Mary*.

Comment: Thank you! Please, tell me what a native speaker would write if he were forced to use the noun "visit" instead of the verb "visit".

Comment: Do you want American English or British English?

Comment: American is preferable, but British is also fine.

Comment: I've given the British version.

Comment: But doesn't your version contain the verb "visit" instead of a noun?

Comment: Oops, I thought I'd edited the answer. I'll try again.

Comment: I see now. Thank you!